# How to show errors in php on ubuntu?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-14.04

Hello everyone I am really new to ubuntu?
I just brought a new ubuntu 14 machine.
I successfully installed apache2 and php5 but unable to see any warnings or error messages on the browser even though i am generating the errors to see them.

Every thing was working good on my old windows machine with XAMPP.

Now I have set the following values into
`/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and /etc/php5/cli/php.ini`

`error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On`

It does not show any errors until I use the following ini_set on each page
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

P.S. - I have also used `echo php_ini_loaded_file();` which shows
`/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`

Please help me :'(

Comment: did you do a `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart` after editing the php.ini? +1 for using ubuntu instead of windows xampp

Comment: no but i did `sudo service apache2 restart`
Would that affect?

Comment: It should. What shows your phpinfo() output for display errors?

Comment: I did your command to just now but no use nad my phpinfo() shows that there is no effect on php.ini `error_reporting : 22527, display_errors: Off` and same for startup errors

Comment: take a look at the path to php.ini listed in phpinfo(). Is it exactly the file you modified?

Comment: its showing `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` do I need to change additional config files too?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check for the "loaded configuration file" in php.ini. If it is the same file then there must be some duplicate "display_errors = Off" line in your php.ini file in your bottom part. The later lines are always taken for execution. So search for all "display_errors" in your php.ini file and remove duplicates. And restart apache. Check phpinfo() output again to find about the "error reporting" variables.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps if you're dealing with PHP 7.4. You should be able to swap out the version number you're dealing with. Step 4 is probably the one you're missing.

1. Create a file with the line `php_ini_loaded_file();` in it.
2. Visit that file. You should see something like `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini`
3. Edit that file and find `display_errors`. Change the value to `On`
4. Go to your terminal and run `sudo service php7.4-fpm restart`